# Редактор странно воспринимает конструкцию using в c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-code, сериализация

Я делал свою игру на юнити, но столкнулся с одним очень неприятным багом. Когда я использую конструкцию using() {}, VS Code выдаёт кучу странных ошибок, которых не должно быть, к примеру: 'Требуется ";" после using', 'Требуется "}" в конце 12 строки' и т.д.

[image: Так это выглядит]

Мне кажется, это баг редактора, возможно он воспринимает using как ссылку на сборку, а может и я что-то забыл сделать.
Жду любой помощи!

Вот код(на всякий случай):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Serialisation
{
    public class Serialisation
    {
        var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var xmlFormatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<int>));
        using (var file = new FileStream("numbers.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            xmlFormatter.Serialize(file, list);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли определить функцию. Просто внутри класса код писать нельзя.

Comment: Так и знал, что что-то забыл... Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пишете код внутри класса, а не внутри метода или конструктора.

```
public class Serialisation
{
    public Serialisation()
    {
        var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var xmlFormatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<int>));
        using (var file = new FileStream("numbers.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            xmlFormatter.Serialize(file, list);
        }
    }
}
```